# Run function continuously on Google App Engine Backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to have a function run either continuously or once every 15 minutes. Since the function will take more time to complete, I need to run it on the Backend (can't use frontend). Currently, I have the process running on the backend but probably not the best way. Here is my backend.yaml file:

```
backends:
- name: mainframe-backend
  start: test.py
  instances: 1
  class: B2
```

My code in test.py is as follows:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(X)
    runcode()
```

I don't think the `While` loop is the best way to go. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) and/or [cron tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) to perform this work. There are a few advantages:

- Automatic retry on failed attempts, with backoff/limits -- you could write this yourself, but why reinvent the wheel?
- For task queues, when there is no work to do, no jobs are running (and billing you for it)
- Simple and documented APIs for configuring the queues and enqueing work -- you can ask SO questions about these and someone can answer them

If you're worried about the request time limit (10m for task queue handlers), you can [send tasks to backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Push_queues_and_backends) where this restriction is lifted.

So in general, I'd ask if it's possible to refactor your workflow into something that can take advantage of the tools provided, so that you don't have to waste the effort reinventing them, or waste the backend processing time (and your money!) with a `while True`.